# Can you cook a 25 lb turkey in an oven that is 9 inches from the bottom rack to the heating elements?

Tags: baking, turkey

I am trying to find out how big an oven has to be to cook a 25 lb. turkey.  There is a new double oven on the market at Sears that has the two ovens about the same size...a standing stove not a built in with two ovens.  The clearance is about 9 inches from the bottom rack to the elements above.  Is 9 inches big enough for a 25 pound bird?

My double oven now is a Maytag 14 years old with two oven, one being small in height and the bottom oven is much larger and does indeed take a 25 pound bird.  I wish I had a 25 pound bird here so I could measure its height.  I like the idea of the two oven being about the same size BUT not sure about a bird.

Comment: Do you cook on a raised rack? That will add an inch to the height of the turkey at least. Even if it's tall enough, it would probably severely limit the airflow. I honestly doubt it would be enough room. How big is your current oven, by the way?

Comment: Have you tried measuring your current oven just for comparison?

Comment: 9" is tiny.  You might be able to fit a [spatchcocked turkey](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/49699/67) if it's wide enough, but there's no way it'd fit even a standard chicken in there in its original shape.

Answer (score 2):

9 Inches in height does indeed sound like it might not be enough to fit the turkey in at all. You also need to take into consideration that you need some space around the bird to allow the heat to spread evenly through the inside of the oven. I would generally not try to cook something in an oven that it barely fits in to.

I did a bit of Googling for you and found this [semi relevant link](http://blog.metrokitchen.com/roasting-pan-guide/) where you find a little table with advised sizes for roasting pans compared to turkey weight.